# Посадка на bitrix нестандартных сайтов

Tags: wordpress, битрикс

Нашёл следующий [нестандартный шаблон](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/)

Как осуществить вёрстку этой темы с учётом того, что хэдер и футер разделены на несколько частей и идут вперемешку с контентом (это не как обычный шаблон в виде простой последовательности хедер - контент - футер, а перемешанный). CMS будет либо WordPress, либо 1С Битрикс.

Хедер и футер статические, а контент динамический.

Comment: а где там футер и хедер разделены?

Comment: футер статичный... хедер статичный..

Comment: слайдер и все что ниже - это контент главной страницы

Comment: Единственное, что тут может быть - это выделить шаблон для главной и шаблон для внутренних страниц.
у внутренних страниц +/- одинаковые шаблоны